# Adding new attributes on RadioButton through MVC model variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, radio-button, editorfor

I have MVC class and one of the variables has been declared as:

```
[UIHint("YesNoRadio")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "test")]
public bool? Emergency { get; set; }
```

this creates HTML as

```
<div class="radio-inline"><label>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Test" id="Emergency" name="Emergency" type="radio" value="true">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline"><label>
<input id="Emergency" name="Emergency" type="radio" value="false">No</label>
</div>
```

what i want is to add new attribute, lets say **div-effect = "emergencyExplain"** and radio button to come as

```
<label><input id="Emergency" name="Emergency" type="radio" value="false" div-effect = "emergencyExplain">No</label>
```

YesNoRadio.cshtml is below:

```
@model bool?    
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label>
        @if (Model.HasValue && Model.Value)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "true", new { @checked = "checked" });
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "true");
        }
        Yes
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label>
        @if (Model.HasValue && !Model.Value)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "false", new { @checked = "checked" });
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "false");
        }
        No
    </label>
</div>
```

and its called as:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Emergency, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

New to MVC form creation so any help in pointing in right direction will be  appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is  "emergencyExplain" the value of a property in your model? And you need to show your `YesNoRadio.cshtml` template

Comment: Yes "emergencyExplain" is the another variable in my model. Didn't knew ````YesNoRadio.cshtml```` was a template, thanks for pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `[UIHint]` attribute just instructs the `EditorFor()` method to use that template. It does not pass any additional data to the template other that the modell property. You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.String,System.Object%29) of `EditorFor()` where you pass the name of the template and an object representing the `additionalViewData`.

You have no shown the model property that contains the value that you want to add to the `data-effect` attribute, but assuming its

```
public string Effect { get; set; }
```

and you set its value in the GET method before you pass the model to the view, then delete the `[UIHint]` attribute from the `Emergency` property and modify the main view to

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Emergency, "YesNoRadio", new { effect = Model.Effect })
```

Then change the `YesNoRadio.cshtml` template to

```
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, true, new { id = "", div_effect = ViewData["effect"] })
        <span>Yes</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, false, new { id = "", div_effect = ViewData["effect"] })
        <span>No</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Which will generate

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Test" div-effect="emergencyExplain" name="Emergency" type="radio" value="True">
```

A few things to note about your current view code.

1. Using `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }`
   wont do anything when using a custom `EditorTemplate` - its only
   applicable using the built-in templates (how would it know which
   element to apply that class to). If you want the class name applied
   to the radio buttons, add that in the `RadioButtonFor()` method in
   the template
2. You do not need to (and should not) set the `checked` attribute.
   That attribute is set by the `RadiobuttonFor()` method based on the
   value of the property (if its `null`,  no buttons will be selected,
   and if its `true` or `false` then the appropriate button will be
   selected
3. Note also the use of `new { id = "" }` which removes the `id`
   attribute which would other wise be generating duplicates which is
   invalid html

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. Exactly what i wanted and learned something new today :).

Comment: You mention that multiple ids with the same value would create invalid HTML. But an attribute like `div-effect` on an HTML element would also be invalid - although it would probably work.